# Coderbyte String Reverse throwing error

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

I'm doing the Coderbyte string reverse challange "First Reverse" and I wrote the code with what I assumed was the right syntax and it threw this error:

```
/tmp/568097195/main.js:30
console.log(FirstReverse(Testing this here));
                     ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
```

But when I check it in my console I get the right output with no syntax errors. Here is my code:

```
var reverseStr = function(str) {
    let arr = str.split(" ").reverse();
    let arr2 = [];
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      arr2.push(arr[i].split("").reverse().join(""));
    }
    return arr2.join(" ");
};
```

Comment: `Testing this here` is not a string or a valid javascript syntax

Answer (score -1):

That is not the correct string syntax, the words need to be surround by quotes `"words here"`, try this:

```
console.log(FirstReverse("Testing this here"));
```